# what the difference between webrequest and httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, .net

It seems that `HttpWebRequest` has more control like `ReadWriteTimeout`. I am wondering whether I should stick with `HttpWebRequest`, rather than `WebRequest`

Comment: See also [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896253/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-vs-webrequest)

Comment: seems like this question repeated every year: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8209781/274502

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`WebRequest` is the base/parent class for `HttpWebRequest` and some other requests as listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest).

For now, they are:

```
  System.IO.Packaging.PackWebRequest
  System.Net.FileWebRequest
  System.Net.FtpWebRequest
  System.Net.HttpWebRequest
```

Answer (score 5):

A [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) can be a [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)/[`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)/[`FileWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.filewebrequest.aspx) (or more in the future...)

Answer (score 0):

I know its too long time but just for information purpose:

**WebRequest**

```
System.Object
    System.MarshalByRefObject
        System.Net.WebRequest
```

The `WebRequest` is an abstract base class. So you actually don't use it directly. You use it through it derived classes - `HttpWebRequest` and `FileWebRequest`.

You use Create method of `WebRequest` to create an instance of `WebRequest`. `GetResponseStream` returns `data stream`.

There are also `FileWebRequest` and `FtpWebRequest` classes that inherit from `WebRequest`. Normally, you would use `WebRequest` to, well, make a request and convert the return to either `HttpWebRequest`, `FileWebRequest` or `FtpWebRequest`, depend on your request. Below is an example:

**Example:**

```
var _request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stackverflow.com");
var _response = (HttpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse();
```

Hope this helps!