# Difference between HttpRequest, HttpWebRequest and WebRequest

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering if somebody explain the difference for the listed classes

Comment: Two related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457791/what-the-difference-between-webrequest-and-httpwebrequest and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896253/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-vs-webrequest both of which with different answers which, to me, doesn't answer the main question here.

Answer (score 45):

They do different things.

[`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) is the abstract base class for `HttpWebRequest` - you can't use it directly. It is the base class of other `*Request` classes (for FTP, File and other types of web requests). These classes are all used for getting resources (files) from the web.

There is also a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class - probably the simplest to use of all the BCL classes designed to retrieve a resource from the Internet.

[`HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx), on the other hand represents a request for a resource in an ASP.NET application - this is the *server side* of a `Request`.

The main difference is that `HttpWebRequest` is an HTTP *client*, and `HttpRequest` is *server* side to be used in an ASP.NET web application.

Comment: about WebRequest I got. But what the difference between HttpRequest and HttpWebRequest?

Comment: How come *"you can't use it directly"*? I use it all the time!

Comment: @Cawas - You can instantiate `WebRequest`?

Comment: From my WebAsync class, which I'm trying to improve: `WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(httpSite);`

Comment: @Cawas - The returned type will not be a `WebRequest` instance, but one of the inheriting classes (say `HttpWebRequest`, `FtpWebRequest` etc...).

Comment: I see... Then, why would I want to enforce and instantiate any other inherited class if this is way more dynamic? Just for code design? If so, then to me, this is the answer for the difference (between `HttpWebRequest` and `WebRequest`, anyway).

Comment: WebClient uses WebRequest under the hood.   Nice!

Comment: You can not instantiate an abstract class, but you can directly reference static members of that class without having to use a derived class, so you can call static method WebRequest.Create() as you do not need an instance of a class to call a static method.

Answer (score 10):

`HttpRequest`, as [Oded already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8209799/274502), is a complete different thing - it generates HTTP Requests at server side so clients (such as `HttpWebRequest`) can read it.

Now, between `HttpWebRequest` and `WebRequest`, while one simply inherits from the other, in practice, there's **no difference if you're using** `http://` when creating the request. *Seems like it's all just about code design.*

To use `WebRequest` we need to `Create`, which will return a descendant class. And as long as we use its instance, it will be acting just as an wrapper to the descendant class. Here's a [remark from the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest):

> `WebRequest` is the **abstract** base class for the .NET Framework's request/response model for accessing data from the Internet. An application that uses the request/response model can request data from the Internet in a protocol-agnostic manner, in which the application works with instances of the `WebRequest` class while protocol-specific descendant classes carry out the details of the request.
>
> (...)
>
> Because the `WebRequest` class is an **abstract** class, the actual behavior of `WebRequest` instances at run time is determined by the descendant class returned by `Create` method. For more information about default values and exceptions, see the documentation for the descendant classes, such as `HttpWebRequest` and `FileWebRequest`.

### Disclaimer

I only got to know this now because, while also looking for the answer (which I didn't know 1h ago), I got this from [forums at codeguru](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?456803-HttpWebRequest-WebRequest-differences) and [MSDN doc remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), all thanks to [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=httpwebrequest%20vs%20webrequest):

> The `HttpWebRequest` class provides support for the properties and methods defined in `WebRequest` **and for additional properties and methods** that enable the user to interact directly with servers using HTTP.

And the remarks go on (selected just ones with *some* relevancy to the difference):

> **Do not** use the `HttpWebRequest` constructor. Use the `WebRequest.Create` method to initialize new `HttpWebRequest` objects. If the scheme for the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is http:// or https://, `Create` returns an `HttpWebRequest` object.
>
> The `GetResponse` method makes a *synchronous* request to the resource specified in the `RequestUri` property and returns an **`HttpWebResponse`** that contains the response. You can make an *asynchronous* request to the resource using the `BeginGetResponse` and `EndGetResponse` methods.
>
> `HttpWebRequest` exposes **common HTTP header values** sent to the Internet resource as properties, set by methods, or set by the system;

Then there's a table [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) I won't quote here.