# Difference between WebRequest and (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest

Tags: c#, .net

What's the difference between:

```
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
```

and

```
WebRequest myRequestWithHttp = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
```

Comment: Also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209781/difference-between-httprequest-httpwebrequest-and-webrequest

Comment: Make it `var myRequestWithHttp =  ..` or there is no difference.