# Unable to call Azure Function App method Api url in c# code

Tags: c#, azure-function-app

I am trying to get data from Azure function APP method (this Get API URL returns the data when directly entered in browser), but failing when I am trying to call this URL in my C# code with following inner exception:

**InnerException    {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}   System.Exception {System.IO.IOException}**

Following is the code:

```
string html = string.Empty;
        string url = @"https://mgyapi.azurewebsites.net/api/my_get/";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url+ "421?code=xxxxxxxxxxwBuTCJpOIVmqBS8DIgE4MhTA==");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.Method = "GET";
        //request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36";
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        //request.ContentLength = formData.Length;
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.Host = "mgyapi.azurewebsites.net";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Timeout = 999999999;
        // ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; 

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) //<----Here exception raises
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Following is the Request Header I see in the browser:

```
Accept: text / html,application / xhtml + xml,application / xml; q = 0.9,image / webp,image / apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Connection: keep-alive
    Host: mgyapi-v1.azurewebsites.net
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
    Sec-Fetch-Site: none
    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Did you check whether the URL is working properly or not?

Comment: Can you compare the `Header` sent by browser when invoked directly vs code?

Comment: @Rohan Rao - I have checked that the URL is working directly in browser.

Comment: @user1672994 - I have added the Request headers seen in the browser.

Comment: @user1400290 - Is Azure function app require minimum version of TLS as 1.2. If no, then change the code as `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12'`

Comment: Also, you don't need to specify `UserAgent `, `CookieContainer `, `Host ` and `Timeout `.If your API returns Json, then define the Contect-Type as application/json.

Comment: There's a known [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1639#issuecomment-320125484) about this, add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` or change Tls to 1.2 in the Azure Function Network SSL.

Answer (score 0):

There are three such methods in ASP.Net for webrequest.

1. HttpWebRequest
2. WebRequest
3. HttpRequest

I am not pointing the difference for the above items. You can find it from here: 
[Difference between HttpWebRequest and WebRequest in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17026797/6029001)

Replace the **HttpWebRequest** with just **WebRequest** and replace all the **HttpWebResponse** with **WebResponse** and see what output you are getting. I think this should solve your problem.